# Pre-select a File in a File Upload Form

Tags: php, forms, joomla2.5

I have a form in Joomla 2.5 the has a file upload option. I want to pre-select a file from the user's local system (namely, in their C:\Windows\TEMP directory; it was put there programmatically by another application).

It's fine if the users can review it, I just need it to select this particular file for them.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't looked into this much or tried it, but you are unlikely to find anything. It would be a major security flaw to allow you to pre pick a file from someone's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reviewing further, David Fritsch is quite correct. There is no way in a modern common browser to inject this information, or even suggest it.